# Orchard ICustomVirtualPathProvider

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to register a ICustomVirtualPathProvider in one of my modules. This is what I am trying to use:

```
public class AzureVirtualPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider, ICustomVirtualPathProvider
{

    public IStaticDataStorageProvider StaticDataStorageProvider { get; set; }

    public VirtualPathProvider Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return this;
        }
    }

    public AzureVirtualPathProvider(IStaticDataStorageProvider staticDataStorageProvider)
    {
        StaticDataStorageProvider = staticDataStorageProvider;
    }

    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
    {
        if (!virtualPath.Contains("StaticData")) return base.FileExists(virtualPath);
        return true;
    }

    public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
    {
        if (!virtualPath.Contains("StaticData") || !StaticDataStorageProvider.IsCloud()) return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
        return new CustomVirtualFile(StaticDataStorageProvider, virtualPath);
    }

}
```

so in Module.Load I am setting:

```
 protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<AzureVirtualPathProvider>().PropertiesAutowired().As<ICustomVirtualPathProvider>();            
    }
```

but this has not been picked up when Orchard calls this line in OrchardStartup.cs (in Orchard.Framework)

```
        if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted) {
            foreach (var vpp in container.Resolve<IEnumerable<ICustomVirtualPathProvider>>()) {
                HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(vpp.Instance);
            }
        }
```

I haver tried calling HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider directly  thus:

```
HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new AzureVirtualPathProvider());
```

and tried to inject the dependency using property injecction:

```
builder.Register(c => new AzureVirtualPathProvider { StaticDataStorageProvider = c.Resolve<IStaticDataStorageProvider>() });
```

however the value for StaticDataStorageProvider is always null when AzureVirtualPathProvider is run.

I have tried moving AzureVirtualPathProvider to OrchardFramework but then it does not resolve StaticDataStorageProvider.

How do I get Orchard to load my CustomVirtualPathProvider?

Comment: Do you need to add it as a reference in Orchard.Web?

Comment: ok, but the code is in a module. It breaks the module pattern to then reference code in a module in orchard.web

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did this:

```
public class OrchardShellEvents : IOrchardShellEvents
    {

        readonly ICustomVirtualPathProvider _customVirtualPathProvider;

        public OrchardShellEvents(ICustomVirtualPathProvider customVirtualPathProvider)
        {
                _customVirtualPathProvider = customVirtualPathProvider;
        }
        public void Activated()
        {
            HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(_customVirtualPathProvider.Instance);
        }

        public void Terminating()
        {

        }
    }
```

I don't know if this is the best solution but it worked and might help someone else.